# Flex spark application container disable scroll bars

Tags: apache-flex, flash, flex4, flexbuilder

First question, do I have to necessarily have a application container as the root node in my mxml file? Second, I was reading [this](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf62d75-7fff.html) document on adobe's website and it says that the spark application container has no scroll bars by default and they can be added by using a custom skin. (Look at the table comparing the mx and spark application containers). But my problem is that my application container already has scroll bars by default and I want to get rid of them. I have a main application container with a custom child component that already has scroll bars. I just want the child to have the scroll bars and not the main application. Right now I get 2 scroll bars nested within each other.

Comment: Sure that you use s:Application, NOT mx:Application?

Comment: Pretty sure it is the sparks container. Even the tool tip says so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized that the problem was being caused by having a horizontal slider in my control bar. If I remove the slider from the control bar the container works as expected that means no scroll bars. To solve the problem with having a slider in the scroll bar just put it inside a Hbox / Vbox. (doesn't matter as slider is the only content I put in there) and then disable the horizontal and vertical scroll bar policy on the enclosing box. Enclosing the slider in a box container magically solves the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Yes I have resolved this problem. I have taken one MX component("Canvas") at outer of flex4 Application component and find out scroll bar enable at application label.